# Regex with non-capturing group in C#

Tags: c#, .net, regex, string-parsing

I am using the following Regex

```
JOINTS.*\s*(?:(\d*\s*\S*\s*\S*\s*\S*)\r\n\s*)*
```

on the following type of data:

```
 JOINTS               DISPL.-X               DISPL.-Y               ROTATION


     1            0.000000E+00           0.975415E+01           0.616921E+01
     2            0.000000E+00           0.000000E+00           0.000000E+00
```

The idea is to extract two groups, each containing a line (starting with the Joint Number, 1, 2, etc.) The C# code is as follows:

```
string jointPattern = @"JOINTS.*\s*(?:(\d*\s*\S*\s*\S*\s*\S*)\r\n\s*)*";
MatchCollection mc = Regex.Matches(outFileSection, jointPattern );
foreach (Capture c in mc[0].Captures)
{
    JointOutput j = new JointOutput();
    string[] vals = c.Value.Split();
    j.Joint = int.Parse(vals[0]) - 1;
    j.XDisplacement = float.Parse(vals[1]);
    j.YDisplacement = float.Parse(vals[2]);
    j.Rotation = float.Parse(vals[3]);
    joints.Add(j);
}
```

However, this does not work: rather than returning two captured groups (the inside group), it returns one group: the entire block, including the column headers. Why does this happen? Does C# deal with un-captured groups differently?

Finally, are RegExes the best way to do this? (I really do feel like I have two problems now.)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

`mc[0].Captures` is equivalent to `mc[0].Groups[0].Captures`.  `Groups[0]` always refers to the whole match, so there will only ever be the one Capture associated with it.  The part you're looking for is captured in group #1, so you should be using `mc[0].Groups[1].Captures`.

But your regex is designed to match the whole input in one attempt, so the `Matches()` method will always return a MatchCollection with only one Match in it (assuming the match is successful).  You might as well use `Match()` instead:

```
  Match m = Regex.Match(source, jointPattern);
  if (m.Success)
  {
    foreach (Capture c in m.Groups[1].Captures)
    {
      Console.WriteLine(c.Value);
    }
  }
```

output:

```
1            0.000000E+00           0.975415E+01           0.616921E+01
2            0.000000E+00           0.000000E+00           0.000000E+00
```

Comment: You know, I actually checked MSDN to find out how the `Captures` property works (I've never used it myself), and I didn't notice that it refers to group 0 (which is obviously the main cause of consternation for the OP). +1!

Answer (score 3):

I would just not use `Regex` for heavy lifting and parse the text.

```
var data = @"     JOINTS               DISPL.-X               DISPL.-Y               ROTATION


         1            0.000000E+00           0.975415E+01           0.616921E+01
         2            0.000000E+00           0.000000E+00           0.000000E+00";

var lines = data.Split('\r', '\n').Where(s => !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(s));
var regex = new Regex(@"(\S+)");

var dataItems = lines.Select(s => regex.Matches(s)).Select(m => m.Cast<Match>().Select(c => c.Value));
```

[image]

Comment: I think I may go with this approach, but using less Linq, as I have to maintain the code and looking at yours I have no idea what's going on...

Comment: Might want to learn Linq because it's really powerful. The last lines matches each line and pulls out everything that isn't a space and then extract the values from the `CaptureCollection` that's inside the `MatchCollection`.

Comment: I admit, it is kinda funny when a guy using regex statements dismisses a linq statement for looking complex. There is power in in being succinct, it applies to linq as well as regexes.

Answer (score 3):

Why not just capture the values and ignore the rest. Here is a regex which gets the values.

```
string data = @"JOINTS DISPL.-X DISPL.-Y ROTATION
 1 0.000000E+00 0.975415E+01 0.616921E+01
 2 0.000000E+00 0.000000E+00 0.000000E+00";

string pattern = @"^
\s+
 (?<Joint>\d+)
\s+
 (?<ValX>[^\s]+)
\s+
 (?<ValY>[^\s]+)
\s+
 (?<Rotation>[^\s]+)";

var result = Regex.Matches(data, pattern, RegexOptions.Multiline | RegexOptions.IgnorePatternWhitespace | RegexOptions.ExplicitCapture)
                  .OfType<Match>()
                  .Select (mt => new
                  {
                    Joint = mt.Groups["Joint"].Value,
                    ValX  = mt.Groups["ValX"].Value,
                    ValY  = mt.Groups["ValY"].Value,
                    Rotation = mt.Groups["Rotation"].Value,
                  });
/* result is
IEnumerable<> (2 items)
Joint ValX ValY Rotation
1 0.000000E+00 0.975415E+01 0.616921E+01
2 0.000000E+00 0.000000E+00 0.000000E+00
*/
```

Answer (score 1):

There's two problems: The repeating part `(?:...)` is not matching properly; and the `.*` is greedy and consumes all the input, so the repeating part never matches even if it could.

Use this instead:

```
JOINTS.*?[\r\n]+(?:\s*(\d+\s*\S*\s*\S*\s*\S*)[\r\n\s]*)*
```

This has a non-greedy leading part, ensures that the line-matching part starts on a new line (not in the middle of a title), and uses `[\r\n\s]*` in case the newlines are not exactly as you expect.

Personally, I would use regexes for this, but I like regexes :-) If you happen to know that the structure of the string will always be [title][newline][newline][lines] then perhaps it's more straightforward (if less flexible) to just split on newlines and process accordingly.

Finally, you can use [regex101.com](http://www.regex101.com/) or one of the many other regex testing sites to help debug your regular expressions.

Comment: Nope, still doesn't work. It gives one big capture group containing everything from JOINTS through to the last floating point number.

Comment: @ian93: Try it now, I fixed the newline handling/start of line handling. Also, why are you using `Matches` if you know there's only going to be one match?

Comment: @Cameron it will match only the first, add `*` or `+` at the end

Comment: @tttony: Oops, I forgot a character when I copied it from where I was testing it. Good catch, thanks :-)