# How to make regexp capture only inner group

Tags: c#, regex

```
   var matches = Regex.Matches("abcde", "(?:ab(c))(d)").Cast<Match>().ToList();
```

In this scenario https://regex101.com/ will tell that 'c' and 'd' were matched.
But .Net will say that there is a group 'abcd' that has one capture 'abcd'.

How to set .net's regex to ignore non-capturing groups but return the inner group capture. 
(it would be great to let it be a solution that allows nesting because I create my regex expression recursively from a tree structure of objects).

Thanks.

Comment: See this answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15170279/regex-with-non-capturing-group-in-c-sharp Or you may find something here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/906493/how-do-i-access-named-capturing-groups-in-a-net-regex

Comment: Thanks I did checked them, but they are like quite the opposite. These guys are glad when regex captures their groups. My problem is that matches1[0].Captures[0].Value captures the whole "abcd" thing. It should only give me "c" and "d" separately

Comment: The first group (group 0) _always_ refers to the input string. The matched groups start at 1.

Comment: I always use named groups. They are not as easily readable but I don't have to count positions when accessing named captures. Example: ab(?<GroupC>c)d

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Match object contains Groups and you need to get your captured texts using `Match.Groups`, not Captures. See [MSDN `Regex.Match` reference](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.regularexpressions.match(v=vs.110).aspx):

> Because a single match can involve multiple capturing groups, `Match` has a [`Groups`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.regularexpressions.match.groups(v=vs.110).aspx) property that returns the [`GroupCollection`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.regularexpressions.groupcollection(v=vs.110).aspx). The `Match` instance itself is equivalent to the first object in the collection, at `Match.Groups[0]` (`Match.Groups(0)` in Visual Basic), which represents the entire match.

Your

```
var matches = Regex.Matches("abcde", "(?:ab(c))(d)").Cast<Match>().ToList();
```

fetches this:

[image]

You can access your values as follows:

```
var first_c= matches[0].Groups[1].Value;
var first_d= matches[0].Groups[2].Value;
```

Using named captures would enable you to access them this way:

```
var matches = Regex.Matches("abcde", "(?:ab(?<myc>c))(?<myd>d)").Cast<Match>().ToList();
var first_c= matches[0].Groups["myc"].Value;
var first_d= matches[0].Groups["myd"].Value;
```